# Vista Device Manager can't open

Tags: windows-vista, device-manager

I am trying to access the device manager from the control panel, and I am getting this error from the MMC window:

> MMC could not create the snap-in. The
>   snap-in may not have installed
>   correctly Name: Device Manager CLSID:
>   {74246BFC-4C96-11D0-ABEF-0020AF6B0B7A}

Do anyone know how to fix this?

This is on a Windows Vista 32, Spyware clean computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to command prompt and type

```
SFC /SCANNOW
```

This should scan and fix any errors with Windows system files.

I have only seen this issue twice, once doing the above fixed it and the other time, I tried diagnosing for hours without coming up with a solution and had to reinstall Windows from scratch.

Lastly, I think this is caused by a corrupt registry key. I never worked out what actually made the problem but it may be worth doing a system restore if you have it turned on as it is possible that it may have created a point before this was an issue.

Hopefully the above will help.

Comment: just ran the command.  It works!  It tell me it found errors, but was not able to fix them all.  But appenrently, it was able to fix this one.